# filter input numbers only

Tags: javascript, regex, input

i am looking to filter my input so it can contain only numbers

```
   re = /[^0-9]/; 
if(!re.test(form.number.value)) {
    alert("Member must contain only numbers. Please try again");
    form.member.focus();
    return false;
}
```

but it didn't work(if i gave for example an input 123fd, it don't give me the error) can anyone help me ?

Comment: When you say it "didn't work", what happened? Was there an error? Was the output different from what you expected? Add some example input and output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your regex is checking for non-digit therefore change negation in your if condition to:

```
re = /\D/; 
if(re.test(form.number.value)) {
   alert("Member must contain only numbers. Please try again");
   // rest of code
}
```

instead of:

```
if(!re.test(form.number.value)) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 input type number to restrict only number entries:

```
<input type="number" name="someid" />
```

Comment: Quite bad since it's clientside stuff, and anyone can tamper it.
No downvote, but no upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($input == intval($input)){
    //OK
 }
```

EDIT sorry it's javascript :

```
 if(input == parseInt(input)){
    //OK
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches anything but digits. When you're negating the test you're essentially saying "match digits" which means that you don't get the alert message for non-digit strings. E.g.:

```
!(/[^0-9]/.test('123'))
// true -> alert

!(/[^0-9]/.test('123fd'))
// false -> don't enter if clause
```

You can fix your code by just removing the exclamation mark in the if-statement. However, a clearer way of expressing your test would be as anubhava mentions:

```
if (/\D/.test(form.number.value)) {
    // validation error
}
```

Where `\D` matches non-digit characters.